# Tomcat: How to Handle SizeLimitExceededException with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf version: 2.4.10

I have a very basic setup for a small project with a contact form in which the users can upload files. I am trying to validate the user input in the controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendHTMLMail", method = POST)
    public String sendHTMLMail(@Valid final ContactEmail contactEmail, BindingResult bindingResult, final Locale locale) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "contactForm.html";
        }
        this.emailService.sendHTMLMail(contactEmail);
        this.emailService.sendHTMLMailToClient(contactEmail);
        return "contactForm.html";

    }
```

my HTML Template is looking like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Very Simple Contact Form</title>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/sendHTMLMail}" th:object="${contactEmail}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="post">

        <label for="clientFirstName">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="clientFirstName" th:field="*{clientFirstName}"><br>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('clientFirstName')}" th:errors="*{clientFirstName}"></label><br>

        <label for="clientLastName">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="clientLastName" th:field="*{clientLastName}"><br>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('clientLastName')}" th:errors="*{clientLastName}"></label><br>

        <label for="clientEmail">Email address:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="clientEmail" th:field="*{clientEmail}"><br>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('clientEmail')}" th:errors="*{clientEmail}"></label><br>

        <label for="emailText">Message:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="emailText" th:field="*{emailText}"><br>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('emailText')}" th:errors="*{emailText}"></label><br>

        <label for="attachments">Attachments:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="attachments" th:field="*{attachments}" multiple/><br>
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('attachments')}" th:errors="*{attachments}"></label><br>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">

    </form>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have set the properties of my tomcat to max upload size like so

```
########################Tomcat file size config############################
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=50MB
```

The model I am trying to validate contains the following properties:

```
 @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String clientFirstName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String clientLastName;
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\..+", message="Your Email must contain: @[domain].com/net/org etc.")
    private String clientEmail;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 500)
    private String emailText;
    @ContactFileConstraint
    private MultipartFile[] attachments;
```

My Custom validator looks like this:

```
public class ClientFileValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<ContactFileConstraint, MultipartFile[]> {
    private static final long VALID_FILE_SIZE = 5242880;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactFileConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return isValidLength(multipartFiles) && isValidSize(multipartFiles) && isValidType(multipartFiles);

    }

    private boolean isValidLength(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
       return multipartFiles.length <= 5;
    }

    private boolean isValidSize(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
        for (int file = 0; file < multipartFiles.length; file++) {
            if (multipartFiles[file].getSize() > VALID_FILE_SIZE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isValidType(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
        for (int file = 0; file < multipartFiles.length; file++) {
            if (!"image/png".equals(multipartFiles[file].getContentType()) &&
                    !"image/jpeg".equals(multipartFiles[file].getContentType())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I try to upload a file bigger than the specified in my custom validator and smaller than the specified max upload size it all works fine and I can see the error on the reloaded page but when the size exceeds 50MB Tomcat itself rejects the request with **SizeLimitExceededException** and it  lands on the default browser page Connection Interrupted.
This can be solved with javascript so it is more user friendly but I want to ask specifically if there is a way to handle a tomcat exception in Spring Boot and handle this with a redirect response from the server side.I already reviewed the solutions in other questions regarding increasing the **server.tomcat.max-swallow-size** but as you can imagine someone can always try to upload a bigger file.

I tried the following options:

1. Using a @ControllerAdvice annotated custom made class:

@ControllerAdvice

```
public class FileUploadExceptionAdvisor {
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String maxUploadSizeExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("attachments", e.getCause().getMessage());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("contactEmail", new ContactEmail());
        return "contactForm";

    }
    @ExceptionHandler(SizeLimitExceededException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(SizeLimitExceededException e){
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

2. Implementing **HandlerExceptionResolver** in my controller

@Override

```
    public ModelAndView resolveException(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            Object o,
            Exception e) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("BasicHTMLFile");

        if (e instanceof SizeLimitExceededException) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        if(e instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException){
            logger.error(e);
        }

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: How about handling the exception in the global error handler?

Comment: Have you tried setting`spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily` to true? This will defer exceptions. I do this and catch the `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` in my exception handler annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.